# C# HttpClient() getStringASync() 404 (Not Found)

Tags: c#

So i'm trying to make a basic Console Application that simply gets the visible text on the webpage.
But for example, if the page is not found, i'm getting an error.
I'm not sure how i'd be able to fix this error, like, if it errors i want it to just ignore it.
I tried adding a if statement but it does the exact same.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.yourwebsite.com/);
```

Comment: Try setting the BaseUrl.  And constructing the rest of the URL and Query String and that is what you pass to your methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you could catch HttpRequestException, but my suggestion do not use GetStringAsync better way use GetAsync method

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.yourwebsite.com");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
  var getResponsestring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else {
  ... your logic here 

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late verification. I think I already solved the problem a while ago, but I'm not that active on Stackoverflow lately. Thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it and I hope others do too.